# SMOTE function not working in make_pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, oversampling, smote

I wanna simultaneously apply cross-validation and over-sampling.
I get the following error from this code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, make_pipeline
imba_pipeline = make_pipeline(SMOTE(random_state=42), 
                              LogisticRegression(C=3.4))
cross_val_score(imba_pipeline, X_train_tf, y_train, scoring='f1-weighted', cv=kf)
```

> ll intermediate steps should be transformers and implement fit and transform or be the string 'passthrough' 'SMOTE(k_neighbors=5, kind='deprecated', m_neighbors='deprecated', n_jobs=1,
>         out_step='deprecated', random_state=42, ratio=None,
>         sampling_strategy='auto', svm_estimator='deprecated')' (type ) doesn't

PS. I get the same error using [imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html) rather than [SMOTE](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should import `make_pipeline` from `imblearn.pipeline` and not from `sklearn.pipeline`: `make_pipeline` from sklearn needs the transformers to implement `fit` and `transform` methods but `SMOTE` does not implement `transform`.

Comment: Thx, you've literally saved my day, seriously didn't know this and was stuck in a bad manner